# What is a good way to run a large number of mocha tests at once from the command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have some mocha tests that I run from a docker container which tests some services in other running docker containers.

Right now, I have a shell script that finds all the mocha js files, de-newlines them and passes them as an argument to mocha itself.  That script then gets run in a docker container as the dockerfile CMD.

This works ok, but it is kind of hacky and is starting to get ugly with several dozen js files.

In javaland, I'd let maven run these, but I figure there must be something better suited for node/javascript.

Comment: Do you mean in parallel when you say 'at once'?

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme  Sequentially, but all in the same mocha execution, so there is a single exit value and test report.   I don't think you could run anything in parallel with mocha without multiple mocha processes.

Comment: If your tests are all in one directory you should be able to turn on recursive mode and just point mocha to that directory. Why do you currently de-newline the scripts and pass them directly? Is it because of docker?

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme I only want to run a certain pattern, i.e. `mocha $(find ./test -name "test-*.js")`.   I didn't see this recursive mode in the docs, found it now and it looks like it takes patterns, e.g. `mocha "tests/**/test-*.js"`   Thanks!   Make an answer and I'll mark it accepted if you want your points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `mocha --recursive path/to/tests` if you want recursively go through all folders and run all files as tests, or you can use globs to pass to mocha like `mocha tests/**/test-*.js` to filter out specific files matching a pattern.